# When I go to play Grand Theft Auto 4, it signs me out of Xbox Live and I can't log back in. Why is this happening?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I go to play GTA 4 and it signs me out when I play and can't get back in, any suggestions?

Comment: Is it signing you out immediately, or after playing for a bit? As your question stands currently, there aren't enough details to provide a conclusive answer.

Comment: Have you tested with other games?

Comment: XBL will often sign you out if you have not accepted a required game patch (these come out all the time).  Also, if you have XBL silver (free version) you may get signed out since this game has online multiplayer (gold only).  Not positive though.

Comment: yeah there was an error with the game because I downloaded it off the marketplace and it was downloaded incorrectly

Comment: Give it a go deleting the game and redownloading it.